# Apache - AliasMatch and htaccess authentication

Tags: apache, .htaccess, alias

I am trying to setup an simple aliasmatch for apache http(s) server. The aim is to allow to reach mydomain.com/myfiles/ with any url like mydomain.com/myfiles*/ without using url rewriting
 I am using a .htaccess file to require an authentication.

My problem is : When I add the AliasMatch directive, the url is recognize but I receive the error `403 forbidden` without receiving the authentication popup window asking for user/password for the basic url as well as for the aliases. What am I missing ?

I tried almost all syntax I could think about around this

```
AliasMatch "^/myfiles(.*)" "/myfiles/$1"
```

In the global conf as well as in the virtualhost conf.

my `Directory` directive

```
<Directory /xxx/xxx/xxxx/myfiles>
   AllowOverride Authconfig
   Require all denied
</Directory>
```

my `.htaccess`

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Required"
AuthUserFile "/xxxx/xxx/xxx"
Require valid-user
```

myfiles is a symlink and working fine when there is not the AliasMacth directive.

Answer (score 0):

your AliasMatch syntax should be 
AliasMatch "^/myfiles(.*)$" "/real/path/to/myfiles/$1"
with '$' and 'real-path'
please try

Comment: I could make it work with : `ALiasMatch "^/myfiles(.*)/(.*)$" "/real/path/to/myfiles/$2"`

Comment: Or not, I am using with autoindex and it seems to get lost. the main page load but I can't reach the content of the directories. It still loads the main page.